# How to mention more relations in a single sentence?

Tags: word-choice

> Uncle Frank & his mother Evelyn fighting each other in court to get
>   custody of Mary.

Here Frank's relation to Mary is Uncle & Evelyn relation to Mary is Grandmother.

I am facing difficulty in phrasing the sentences because of single person having more than one relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "Uncle Frank", most people would assume the you are talking about **your** uncle, not Mary's uncle. It would be easier if you start the sentence with the main person in the story... Mary.

> Mary's Uncle, Frank, and her grandmother, Evelyn, are fighting in court to get custody of her.

Comment: That still leaves it open as to whether Frank is an "uncle" by *marriage* (Mary being the daughter of his wife's sibling), or by blood (Mary's mother or father being a sibling of Frank himself). More crucially, it doesn't indicate whether Evelyn is Frank's mother or just another "in-law", but since OP specifically noted that in his original, it could be a significant factor.

Answer (score 1):

Mary's uncle Frank is fighting his mother, Evelyn, in court to get custody of Mary.